# Line plane intersection: what is this variable?

Tags: mathematics, linear-algebra

I'm doing line plane intersection, and have come across an un-referenced variable or constant in the [tutorial I'm following](http://www.thepolygoners.com/tutorials/lineplane/lineplane.html).

One of the formulae given is this:

t = N dot (p2 – p0)
     N dot V

The variable I'm stuck with is `V`. Can someone tell me what `V` is and how I'd go about finding it?

For more info on that formula, please see the link given in the first para.

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like V = p1 - p0. Since then t = 0 when p2 = p0, and t = 1 when p2 = p1.

Comment: Thanks so much :-) just the answer I needed. I'd vote you up but I have 1 rep :-P

Comment: No worries! :) Glad it helped...